# Is media queries the only way to support multiple screen sizes

Tags: cordova

First time working with phonegap/cordova here.

I want the app to look good on different phones such as Galaxy series and iPhone series.
They all have different resolutions and I was wondering how phonegap handles them?

Is media query the only answer?

```
/* iPhone 5/5S */
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {

}

/* iPhone 6 */
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 375/667) {
}

/* iPhone 6+ */
....
and more
```

I don't like how I have to style for each phone. It seems very time consuming to test them on each simulators and changing CSS accordingly.

Any tips on doing this more efficiently?

Comment: If you think the answer is good enough you should accept it. That's the way SO works. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess with Cordova and HTML5 that's the only way.

Since you're using Cordova I would suggest you to use a mobile framework like [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) or [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/).
Another one which is quite popular is [Famous](http://famo.us/).

**Ionic** is built using **angularJs** so you'll be forced to learn that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use frameworks, you can also try `cordova-screengod`:

https://github.com/biodiv/cordova-screengod

```
 screengod(['path/to/your.css'],function(){
      /* do your stuff */
 });
```

after deviceready and it will look the same on all screens. You might have to adjust your css values though...